# Inline-block with paragraph keeps jumping

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to make 3 boxes next to each other with text in. So far I got the boxes setup right. But when I add text it jumps up and down. When I enter the same amount of paragraph tags in a div they all align. But when one div has 1 paragraph tag and the others have 2 they aren't aligned anymore.
I'm not sure how to solve this.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/gegc8nuk/

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: table;
  /* Webkit Fix */
  width: 100%;
  /* set width to stop display table shrink to fit */
  word-spacing: -1em;
  /* hide whitespace nodes (not in webkit) - will never overlap even if zoomed */
}
.tox {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  word-spacing: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5%;
  /* reset parent */
}
.red {
  background-color: #9a0000;
}
.green {
  background-color: #4ce215;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #240fc3;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="tox red span-1-of-3">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tox green span-1-of-3">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tox blue span-1-of-3">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What is meaning of *"jumps up and down"*.

Comment: to vertical-align inline-block element side by side use ... `vertical-align:top;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use once display:table; why don't you use table-cells on childs ?

https://jsfiddle.net/gegc8nuk/1/

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
  /*padding: 80px 0;*/
}
.wrap {
  display: table;     
  width: 100%;
  /* set width to stop display table shrink to fit 
   word-spacing: -1em;
  hide whitespace nodes (not in webkit) - will never overlap even if zoomed */
}
.tox {
  display: table-cell;
  /* height: 200px; */
  /*width: 100%;
  word-spacing: 0;*/
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5%;
  /* reset parent */
}
.red {
  background-color: #9a0000;
}
.green {
  background-color: #4ce215;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #240fc3;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="tox red span-1-of-3">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tox green span-1-of-3">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tox blue span-1-of-3">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Haha I feel so stupid i tottaly looked over that .. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

With your css you have set `tox` with 100% width while keeping `inline-block`, while applied `wrap` as `display: table;` . Both are different. You can do the following:

Edit your CSS:

```
.wrap {
    display: block;
    /* Webkit Fix */
    width: 100%;
    /* set width to stop display table shrink to fit */
    word-spacing: -1em;
    /* hide whitespace nodes (not in webkit) - will never overlap even if zoomed */
}
.tox {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding: 10px;
    word-spacing: 0;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* reset parent */
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/gegc8nuk/2/